# How to change name of Radio button dynamically

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to develop online exam system in that i retrieve questions & Option from database.

When I use while loop all radio button got same name.I want Every questions option have different name.

How to dynamically change the name of the radio button for every question & after that i want to get value of every selected radio button in one array.

Comment: <input type="radio" name='xyx[<?php echo $i; ?>]'/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In loop you can do Unique name for the radio button like this :

```
<input type="radio" name="opt_'.<?php echo $option_value; ?>.'"/>
```

where `$option_value` is that of options value from database.

Comment: hey,I tried the same thing after that i want to get selected radio button in one array to use further how i can do this i use

Comment: hey,I tried the same thing after that i want to get selected radio buttons in one array to use further I got seleted values in URL but when  trying to get on page it gives mi error

Comment: We can help you more if you provide us code. And if there is any new question please [Ask that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)